# how to change mailed by default value in the email header

Tags: php, email, header, email-headers

I want to give mailed by value as my domain name (xyz.com) in the email header, instead of challenger websitewelcome.com, etc. And also I want to change from email id in the email header.  How can I solve the above problem, I am using PHP script to send an email. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the following code, I hope it will solve your problem

```
<?php
$to = "xxx@domain.com"; // To address email id
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: your company name <yyy@email.com> \r\n"; // from email address
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers,"-fyyy@email.com"); // this will remove mailed by default value to your domainname
?>
```

Note in the mail function last parameter is mandatory "-f" //yyy@email.com need to be add without space